Coordinate map for once-punctured torus
Ultimate goal: Be able to draw geodesics on the once-punctured torus similarly to how it is done in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26749/plotting-a-contour-on-a-torus
It is fairly well known that, from the 2D representation of the torus as the quotient $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]/\sim$ where opposite edges are identified, one has the following function which maps this space to the 3D representation of the torus:
\begin{align*}
x &= \cos(2 \pi u) \\
y &= \sin(2 \pi u) \\
z &= \sin(2 \pi v)
\end{align*}
up to some scaling factors I'm not concerned with right now. Here, $(u, v)$ are the coordinates of the square in the 2D plane.
I want to know if there is a similar coordinate map when one considers the fundamental domain form of the once-punctured torus in the upper-half plane model of $\mathbb{H}^{2}$, that being the region in the upper complex plane between $-1 \leq \mathrm{Re}(z) \leq 1$ except for the two semicircles centered at $(\pm 0.5, 0)$ with radii $0.5$.
If such a thing exists, it should be possible to plot in Mathematica a figure like https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-simple-curve-on-the-punctured-torus_fig1_226685228, including mapping curves in the upper half plane onto the once-punctured torus.

While not a perfect answer, I found a paper that does provide more detailed calculations on the once-punctured torus using triangle length coordinates and Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates, although these are coordinates seemingly more designed for Techmuller spaces.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.06609
